# How to disable BTRFS copy-on-write updates for a subvolume using btrfs-property instead of chattr

Tags: btrfs, copy-on-write

I want to disable BTRFS copy-on-write updates for a subvolume using the newer method `btrfs property` instead of the old method `chattr`.

I found the man page here:
[Manpage/btrfs-property - btrfs Wiki](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Manpage/btrfs-property)

This quote leads me to believe it has the functionality I desire:

> btrfs property provides an unified and user-friendly method to tune different btrfs properties instead of using the traditional method like chattr(1) or lsattr(1)

However, I need an example that will replicate this command:

```
chattr +C /path/to/my/subvolume/.cache
```

where `.cache` is a BTRFS subvolme.

Comment: What does `btrfs property list /path/to/my/subvolume/.cache` show?

Comment: @rickhg12hs it only lists `ro`, `label`, and `compression` and no other properties. Surely there are more properties available... or is that it?

Comment: I think that's it so far.

Comment: https://github.com/kdave/btrfs-progs/blob/9a85732d8beaae4b80cab98bb3355660389c1d36/props.c#L169

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In October 2020, it seems that only `ro` (read-only), `label`, and `compression` are the only properties available via `btrfs property ...` at this time.